# Error in use of Conditional Operator

Tags: c#, conditional-operator

My code is like this:

```
if (statusCode== "1")
{
    statusCode = productStatusItemAvailable1;
}
else if(statusCode =="2")
{
    statusCode = productStatusItemOutOfStock1;
}
 else if(statusCode =="3")
{
    statusCode = productStatusItemAvailableOnRemoteDate1;
}
else if(statusCode =="4")
{
    statusCode = productStatusAlternativeItemAvailable1;
}
else if(statusCode =="5")
{
    statusCode = productStatusItemSoldOutAndOurSuppliersHaveNoAvailable;
}
else if(statusCode =="6")
{
    statusCode = productStatusItemSoldOutContactCustomerService1;
}
```

To make it little more readable and easy to handle I tried to apply Ternary Operator

```
statusCode == "1"  ? productStatusItemAvailable1: "2" ? productStatusItemOutOfStock1 : "3" ? productStatusItemAvailableOnRemoteDate1  : "4"  ? productStatusAlternativeItemAvailable1 : "5" ? productStatusItemSoldOutAndOurSuppliersHaveNoAvailable : "6" ? productStatusItemSoldOutContactCustomerService1;
```

But this shows an error

> Can not implicitly convert string to bool.

What am I doing wrong?Or is it not possible to use with strings?

Comment: A ternary operator means "an operator with three operands". If you're trying to chain an entire series of ternary operators together to compare against a set of values one by one, you're probably not using the ternary conditional operator as intended. You should definitely use a switch/case instead.

Comment: Well the second one you aren't checking whether `statusCode=="2"` you are just saying is "2" true, which is non-sensical

Comment: Wow. Have you ever heard of `switch`?

Comment: Creating an enumeration for your error codes and parsing the 'number' before a switch statement will make the code more maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out, you aren't checking the value against the string. That said, you should definitely use a switch statement for this:

```
switch(statusCode)
{

    case "1":
        // do some stuff
    break;

    // etc...
}
```

Though ideally, `statusCode` should be an enum where each value corresponds to the error, it will make your code clearer.

Answer (score 4):

You need a `statuscode ==` for every condition

`statusCode == "1" ? product1 : statusCode == "2" ? product2` ... etc

Comment: He doesn't assign the return value.

Answer (score 3):

The sintaxe for [`?:` Ternary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is:

```
object result = bool ? object : object;
```

In your code, you did not define anything after the `:` scope, to use like this, you could define another ternary scope after the `:` and apply it again, something like:

```
  statusCode  = statusCode == "1" ? productStatusItemAvailable1 : 
                statusCode == "2" ? productStatusItemOutOfStock1 : 
                statusCode == "3" ? productStatusItemAvailableOnRemoteDate1 : 
                statusCode == "4" ? productStatusAlternativeItemAvailable1 : 
                statusCode == "5" ? productStatusItemSoldOutAndOurSuppliersHaveNoAvailable : 
                statusCode == "6" ? productStatusItemSoldOutContactCustomerService1 
                : stirng.Empty;
```

The last `:` scope of ternary, is like the last `else` statment of an `if` structure. you have to define a value as a `default` value for it, because it is part of the structure of ternary operator.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably be better off using a [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx), or a dictionary:

```
var statusCodes = new Dictionary<string, string>{};
statusCodes.Add("1", productStatusItemAvailable1); // For each message
```

Now you can get each message using the key:

```
// Will return value of productStatusItemAvailable1:
var result = statusCodes["1"];
```